# How can I animate one View after another instead of all at the same time?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-linearlayout

I am adding `TextViews` dynamically to a `LinearLayout`. I want to animate each `View` so they slide in one after another from the left. This is what I currently have:

```
for ( int i=0; i < SOME_SIZE; i ++ ) {
    linearLayout.addView(addLessonsView(i))
}

public View addLessonsView(int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_memory_book_lessons, null);

    TextView tvLesson = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLesson);

    tvLesson.setText(mLessonList.get(position).getLessonNumber() + " - " + mLessonList.get(position).getLessonName());

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.slide_left_to_right);
    tvLesson.startAnimation(animation);

    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

The problem is that all of the `Animations` happen at the same time instead of one after another. How can I slide the `Views` in one after another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting all `Animation`s at the same time which is why all of the `View`s slide in at the same time. What you need to do is add a start offset to each `Animation` which corresponds to its position in the `List`.

For example to delay each `Animation` to play 75ms after the one before it you can do this:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.slide_left_to_right);

final long startOffset = position * 75;
animation.setStartOffset(startOffset);

tvLesson.startAnimation(animation);
```

---

Additionally I suggest you switch to the newer Animator API which was introduced Android 3.0 (Honeycomb). The old view animations you are using are outdated to say the least.

Click [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) to get started with the newer API.

Comment: worked like charm! thanks buddy. thanks for the newer animation API suggestion as well, didn't know that the one i am using are out dated.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented **Xaver Kapeller**'s solution to animate 52 ImageView (one Deck of cards) one after another.

Though, It worked fine for up-to 24 ImageViews, I got "force close" when I wanted to animate 25 ImageViews one after another.

To overcome this issue, I implemented a `Handler` and `onAnimationEnd` to animate next ImageView after the previous one.

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.navigator.deck.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sj"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hj"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dj"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cj"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And MainActivity.java:

```
package com.navigator.deck;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final List<ImageView> cards = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s1));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s2));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s3));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s4));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s5));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s6));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s7));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s8));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s9));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s10));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sj));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sq));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sk));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.h1));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.h2));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.h3));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.h4));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.h5));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.h6));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.h7));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.h8));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.h9));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.h10));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hj));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hq));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hk));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d1));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d2));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d3));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d4));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d5));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d6));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d7));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d8));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d9));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d10));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dj));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dq));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dk));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c1));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c2));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c3));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c4));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c5));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c6));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c7));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c8));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c9));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c10));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cj));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cq));
        cards.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ck));

        final TranslateAnimation  animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,100,0,100);
        animation.setDuration(100);     
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message message)
            {
                cards.get(0).startAnimation(animation);
                return false;
            }
        });
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) 
            {               
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) 
            {   
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
            {
                cards.get(0).setX(cards.get(0).getX()+ 100);
                cards.get(0).setY(cards.get(0).getY()+100);
                cards.remove(0);
                if (cards.size()>0)
                {
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                }
            }
        });
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }
}
```